# Sympy matrix substitution using a dictionary

Tags: python, sympy

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208838/sympy-substitute-sybolic-entries-in-a-matrix) but I do not see an answer. I would like to substitue numerical values into a sympy matrix. In more detail, I do establish a system in sympy and on some occasions I would like to plug in numerical values based on numpy arrays. I thought it is possible using dictionaries. But either I misunderstood the concept or it is not a feature of the language.

I do have a matrix:

```
import sympy as sp
cp = sp.MatrixSymbol('cp',3,3)
C = sp.Matrix(cp)
sp.pprint(Q)

⎡cp₀₀  cp₀₁  cp₀₂⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎢cp₁₀  cp₁₁  cp₁₂⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎣cp₂₀  cp₂₁  cp₂₂⎦
```

I create a dictionary

```
mydict={'cp', sp.Matrix(np.random.rand(3,3))}
```

But substitution does not work:

```
mydict = {'cp':sp.Matrix(cp)}
subs = C.subs(mydict)
sp.pprint(subs)
```

Output (should be numeric):

```
⎡cp₀₀  cp₀₁  cp₀₂⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎢cp₁₀  cp₁₁  cp₁₂⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎣cp₂₀  cp₂₁  cp₂₂⎦
```

If i use a numpy array instead of the sympy matrix I get following error:

`SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse u'[[ 0.69780014  0.89835127  0.9623417 ] [ 0.28375306  0.94416287  0.12325111] [ 0.20154648  0.7324886   0.87209933]]'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`

This try gave the same error (substituting the exact variable names):

```
mydict2 = {}
i,j = C.shape
[ mydict2.update( {C[i,j]: cp[i,j]} )for i in range(i) for j in range(j)]
C.subs(mydict2)
```

Any clue ?

EDIT: As an answer to a comment I post what my output should look like:

If i generate a random matrix (I tried sp.Matrix, np.matrix, and np.array):

```
sp.Matrix(np.random.rand(3,3))

⎡0.12  0.87  0.96⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎢0.31  0.71  0.44⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎣0.36  0.23  0.55⎦
```

and substitue (like shown above) this matrix into the symbolic one, I expected the symbolic matrix look like the numeric one.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want as the output? Which substition should be performed? Do you want block-matrices?

Comment: No, I tried to substitute with numerical values based on a numpy array

Comment: Can you add what exactly you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the reasons for wanting a sympy Matrix filled with numbers originating from numpy still elude me, you could perform the substitution like this:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

cp = sp.MatrixSymbol('cp',3,3)
C = sp.Matrix(cp)  # same thing as cp.as_explicit()
C.subs(list(zip(cp, np.random.rand(9))))
# example output:
#
# Matrix([
# [0.993152112961882, 0.898596737383104, 0.403274559253394],
# [0.831318080769803, 0.296307294254107,  0.57444787963296],
# [0.424120969168281, 0.985130115570423, 0.113035586132516]])
```

I'm using an extra call to `list` because I'm using Python3, where `zip` doesn't return a list anymore, but a generator. Without it, in Python3, you'd get:

```
 Matrix([
[0.0798937249416819, cp[0, 1], cp[0, 2]],
[          cp[1, 0], cp[1, 1], cp[1, 2]],
[          cp[2, 0], cp[2, 1], cp[2, 2]]])
```

Just added to be complete.

Comment: Probably, I am not thinking straight. I have some system set up in numpy and  call fsolve to solve it. The system itself changes its size depending on the number of component present (proteins). I would like to provide an analytical gradient using sympy.  and plug the matrices from numpy into the sympy matrix. I just found lambdify. Maybe it would be a better way to evaluate the expressions.