# How do I replace each entry in my Matrix with a random integer?

Tags: sympy

I want to generate an n x m Matrix where each entry is a different number. The purpose of this program is to generate matrices so that I can then practice the technique of reducing these matrices to reduced row-echelon form via Gaussian elimination.

```
from sympy import MatrixSymbol,Eq
import random
k=0
def random_value(k):
    return random.choice([k for k in range(-4,4) if k not in [0]])

rowlength = abs(random_value(k))
columnlength = abs(random_value(k))
C = MatrixSymbol('C',rowlength ,columnlength)
display(Eq(C,C.as_explicit()))
for i in range(0,rowlength):
    for j in range(0,columnlength):
        p = C.as_explicit().row(i).col(j)
        display(p[0])
display(Eq(C,C.as_explicit()))
#display(C.rref()[0])
```

I tried `p[0] == random_value(k)` and it gave me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set values of <class 'sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix'>
```

I am assuming the problem is that the Matrices I am generating are immutable.

I looked at the similar post [SymPy - substitute sybolic entries in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208838/sympy-substitute-sybolic-entries-in-a-matrix) and did not see a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SymPy has a `randMatrix` function:

```
In [16]: randMatrix(3, 4)
Out[16]: 
⎡78  25  63  64⎤
⎢              ⎥
⎢83  72  43  91⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎣82  81  71  66⎦
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.randMatrix

Comment: Any suggestions for generating random augmented Matrices? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix

Comment: I edited my original post to include updated code and further questions. I am not sure how I could mimic augmented matrix notation in Sympy. Reading https://towardsdatascience.com/how-do-you-use-numpy-scipy-and-sympy-to-solve-systems-of-linear-equations-9afed2c388af right now.

Comment: Please don't change the question after asking it (ask a new question). Also I recommend avoiding articles from towardsdatascience.com because I have seen poor quality advice there.